# transaction ID and payment object in Magento

Tags: php, magento, variables

My question might looks vogue, but I am facing difficult over it..

part of function code is

```
 public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount){

            if(!$this->isEnabled()){
                return parent::capture($payment, $amount);
            }else{
    ---- MORE CODE--
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $nickname = $quote->getAuthorizenetNickname();
        $profile = $quote->getProfile();
        $postedNickname = $quote->getNickname();

        if ($payment->getCcTransId()) {
        $payment->setAnetTransType(self::REQUEST_TYPE_PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE);
        } else {
        $payment->setAnetTransType(self::REQUEST_TYPE_AUTH_CAPTURE);
        }

        $payment->setAmount($amount);

        $request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);
        $result = $this->_postRequest($request);

        MORE CODE HERE, NOT RELEVENT TO MY ISSUE
```

I got two question here

**HOW CAN I PASS TRANSACTION ID IN**

```
$payment->setAmount($amount);   
$request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);
$result = $this->_postRequest($request);
```

and 2nd question is

> how can I Echo / debug value of transactionID being passed

might be very easy for you, but I am at failure

**tried so far**

```
$payment->setTransID($payment->gerOrder->getTransID());   
and 
$payment->gerOrder->getTransID()
$payment->setAmount($amount);   
$request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);
```

thanks for your help and guideline

Comment: Which class contains function _buildRequest and what exactly do you expect that function does with transaction id?

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/load-transaction-data-by-id-magento-2/ load transaction data

Answer (score 8):

I have ran through this issue before and here is my findings :)

Payment is completely different from Transaction although they have a relation.

Payment objects holds complete information about the order totals ( discounts , grand total, canceled , shipping , etc... )

Transaction only hold the information related to if for instance from payment gateway ( `txn_id`,`parent_txn_id` - if it has parent trans  - ,etc... ) so it's not away of how much paid/how much left/how much cancelled/shipped etc..

- Payment has One-To-Many Relation with Transaction ( so you cant set Transaction Id to it ) You need to set last_trans_id to the payment or if it's credit card transaction ( onetime ) You can set and use this field cc_trans_id 
  In other words How to assign transaction to payment, you need to do as follow:-

  - Create New Payment Object assigned to the order and save all your data etc.. ( or if you coming back from payment gateway you load the order/quote and get the payment object `$order->getPayment();` )
  - Create Transaction Object assign it to that paymentID and order ID , etc.. Then save it
  - Assign `last_trans_id` to the payment object and save it !
  - Then save the order with that payment object or save the payment object its already assigned to that order.

I hope this helps you :)

Please find the code Example of payment integration I have done to add transaction to the payment

```
    /**
 * Creates Transactions for directlink activities
 *
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 * @param int $transactionID - persistent transaction id
 * @param int $subPayID - identifier for each transaction
 * @param array $arrInformation - add dynamic data
 * @param string $typename - name for the transaction exp.: refund
 * @param string $comment - order comment
 * 
 * @return Cashu_Helper_DirectLink $this
 */
public function directLinkTransact($order,$transactionID, $subPayID,
    $arrInformation = array(), $typename, $comment, $closed = 0)
{
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $payment->setTransactionId($transactionID."/".$subPayID);
    $transaction = $payment->addTransaction($typename, null, false, $comment);
    $transaction->setParentTxnId($transactionID);
    $transaction->setIsClosed($closed);
    $transaction->setAdditionalInformation("arrI    nfo", serialize($arrInformation));
    $transaction->save();
    $order->save();
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: any code line example, if you can please? or some psudo code??

Answer (score 2):

I'm also in the process of building a CIM payment module. So i know exactly what your going thru (I think I'm almost finish, but then again I have been saying that for the last 3 weeks)

From your code above it seem like you are trying to do a `PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE` which mean that you should have store the transaction id when you did `AUTH_ONLY` transaction.

Take a look at

> /app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php

Code to set transaction id (`PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE`)

```
protected function _preauthorizeCaptureCardTransaction($payment, $amount, $card)
{
    $authTransactionId = $card->getLastTransId();
    $authTransaction = $payment->getTransaction($authTransactionId);
    $realAuthTransactionId = $authTransaction->getAdditionalInformation($this->_realTransactionIdKey);

    $payment->setAnetTransType(self::REQUEST_TYPE_PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE);
    $payment->setXTransId($realAuthTransactionId);
```

Code to saving transaction id (`AUTH_ONLY`)

```
protected function _place($payment, $amount, $requestType)
{
    ....
    switch ($result->getResponseCode()) {
        case self::RESPONSE_CODE_APPROVED:
            $this->getCardsStorage($payment)->flushCards();
            $card = $this->_registerCard($result, $payment); //<-- take a look at

    .....

    $this->_addTransaction(
          $payment,
          $card->getLastTransId(),
          $newTransactionType,
          array('is_transaction_closed' => 0),
          array(
              $this->_realTransactionIdKey => $card->getLastTransId(), //<-- take a look at
              $this->_isTransactionFraud => true
          ),
```

Update

```
$payment->setAmount($amount);   
$payment->setXTransId({put your transaction id here});
$payment->setAnetTransType($requestType);
$request= $this->_buildRequest($payment);
$result = $this->_postRequest($request);
```

Then when building your request

```
protected function _buildRequest(Varien_Object $payment)
{
   ....
   switch ($payment->getAnetTransType()) {
   .....
        case self::REQUEST_TYPE_PRIOR_AUTH_CAPTURE: //<-- for all the request that need Transaction id 
            $request->setXTransId($payment->getXTransId());
            break;
```

Comment: you got me quite near buddy, but my issue is not how can I save transaction ID, I am already at success for this, my issue is, I am unable to pass it it PRIOR_AUT_CAPTURE transaction...

Comment: you saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328475/auth-net-issue-on-capture?